# How to pass variable into function to another one with or without class method

Tags: php, function, global-variables

I created a WordPress plugin using CURL to automatically get the country ISO language of the user and redirect this one to take it to the page corresponding to its language.

I need to pass the output of first function to the second to add a filter to template_redirect that will allow me to rewrite the url on the fly.

I tried global, class method and public function, but every time it doesn't work:

I want to pass the output of `getusercountrycode()` to `atv_redirect()`:

```
//try/ class atvRed {
    //try/ public function __construct( ){
            //add_action('template_redirect',  array( $this,'atv_redirect'));
    //try/ }
//try/ add public after function

function getusercountrycode(){
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $ch = curl_init();
    $curlConfig = array(
        CURLOPT_URL            => "https://get.geojs.io/v1/ip/country/{$ip}.json",
        CURLOPT_POST           => true,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => false
    );
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $curlConfig);
    $countrycode = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $countrycode = json_decode($countrycode);
    //try/ $countrycode = strtolower($countrycode);
    //try/ global $countrycode;
    return $countrycode;
}
//try/ $visitorlang = getusercountrycode();

function atv_redirect(){
    //try/ global $countrycode;
    if ( !function_exists( 'getusercountrycode' ) ) {
        return;
    }else{
    
        $geoip =  getusercountrycode();
        $visitorlang ="";
        foreach ($geoip as $infoip => $ipvalue){
            if($infoip == 'country'){
                $visitorlang =  $ipvalue;
            }
        }
        //global $countrycode;
        //$visitorlang = strtolower($countrycode);

        $atvdomain = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
        $currentpage = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; 
        $listlangs = 'fr|en';
        $addlang = "/fr";
        $langsltd = "fr";
        //$visitorlang = '/'.$visitorlang;

        //if(preg_match ('/^(?:(?!'.$visitorlang.').)*$/i', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])){
        //if(preg_match ("/^(?:(?![a-z]{2}).)*$/i", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])){
        if(preg_match ("/^(?:(?!fr).)*$/i", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])){
            wp_safe_redirect($addlang.'/'.$currentpage);
        }
    }
}
add_action('template_redirect','atv_redirect');
//try/ }$atvRew = new atvRed();
```

Comment: `getusercountrycode()` returns an object, not an array. Use `$geoip->country`

Comment: What kind of debugging did you try? `var_dump($geoip);` would be a good start.

Comment: Just do it in the mathematical way `$a = func_a(); $b = func_b($a);` or simplier `$b = func_b(func_a())`. Avoid the use of global.

Comment: @barnar : Yes for $geoip->country. The country code is well retrieve (var_dump well works), I can't pass it to atv_redirect() .

Comment: @markus-zeller: I don't really understand , how $b = func_b($a); retrieve the output of func_a and how I can exploit it inside func_b()?

Comment: Read the basics about functions and return values. https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/
define `atv_redirect` to accept an argument and modify `add_action` accordingly. When you use `do_action`, pass the result of `getusercountrycode`.

Comment: I can't make sense of what you are asking, not at all. `$geoip =  getusercountrycode();` - after this you will _have_ the return value of the `getusercountrycode` call in that variable - so where do you think you'd need to "pass" anything else around now to begin with here ...?

Comment: `I want to pass getusercountrycode() output to atv_redirect():`...it's unclear what you mean. Seeing as the call to `getusercountrycode()` is within the `atv_redirect()` function, the value it returns is in `$geoip`, which is already inside the function. You can use it as normal within the function. It's not clear what you want to pass to where. At a guess...are you actually wanting to return `$geoip` _from_ atv_redirect(), as the output of that function?? Please give us a clearer description / example of what you are trying to achieve, so we can help you properly. Thanks.

Comment: @adyson: log says  getusercountrycode() undefined inside atv_redirect(). I work with Wordpress I don't know if class method is indispensable .

Comment: What _exactly_ is the error message, and which line is throwing it? Please never paraphrase or abbreviate error messages. It just creates uncertainty and makes it difficult to give precise help. In programming, details are always important. Please [edit] your question whenever you have important information like this. And if you were getting an error message, I have no idea why you didn't tell us this already??

Comment: @clash : do you mean that ?: ` do_action( 'my_action', 'getusercountrycode' ); function my_function( $default_output ) { $geoip =  $default_output;}`

Comment: @adyson: Hi , how can I improve this question and its score ? Must I add all research that I have done (global var, class method, etc) ? I need help to convert  php Regex to  javascript and I can't ask no more question. Thanks.

Comment: It just would have needed to actually make sense. What you said, and the code you posted, didn't match at all. But you've already posted an answer yourself, and the question is also closed and on the list for deletion, so even if you edit it, I doubt anyone would be very interested. You can always delete it yourself, too (with [some caveats](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)). Your ban on asking new questions will be lifted after a period of time, I think, you'll just need to be patient - please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking-rate-limited.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for that, beginner's mistake :
I tested a lot of code and forgot to comment out the lines of code that could cause a conflict by reusing the same variables.

work perfectly :

```
$geoip =  getusercountrycode();
$visitorlang = $geoip->country;
$visitorlang = strtolower($visitorlang);
```

and also that :

```
$geoip =  getusercountrycode();
$visitorlang = "";
foreach ($geoip as $infoip => $ipvalue){
    if($infoip == 'country'){
            $visitorlang =  $ipvalue;
        }
        // forgot to return -> return $visitorlang;
    }
$visitorlang = strtolower($visitorlang);
```